# Why is my Selenium scraper being redirected to a scam bitcoin site?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I have the following scraper:

```
from selenium import webdriver


class ScraperSelenium:

    def __init__(self):
        self._driver = self.get_driver()

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        self._close_browser()

    def get_driver(self):
        options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
        options.add_argument('--user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows Phone 10.0; Android 4.2.1; Microsoft; Lumia 640 XL LTE) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.135 Mobile Safari/537.36 Edge/12.10166"')
        options.add_argument("--blink-settings=imagesEnabled=false")
        options.add_argument("--log-level=3")
        options.add_argument("--ignore-certificate-errors")
        options.add_argument("--ignore-ssl-errors")
        options.add_argument("no-sandbox")
        return webdriver.Firefox(options=options, executable_path=<geckodriver_path>)

    def scrape_html(self, url):
        self._driver.get(url)
        return self._driver.page_source

    def _close_browser(self):
        self._driver.quit()


with ScraperSelenium() as scraper:
    html = scraper.scrape_html("https://www.atptour.com/en/rankings/singles")
```

However, when I run it the scraper gets redirected to a dodgy bitcoin investing site.

Any ideas on what might be going on?

Answer (score 0):

Given that this is a very basic script, try running it on a different browser (Chrome), if the same result happens, try it in a different system.

If it works on Chrome, it is likely that your Firefox settings have been altered by third-party apps or viruses, so double check them.

If it doesn't work on Chrome, it will most likely work on a different system, but you should check your DNS settings.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! Runs fine with Chrome so your hunch looks to be correct. Weirdly I can open the atptour.com site with no problem on Firefox. I'd like to use Firefox if possible but I've tried refreshing the Firefox settings, deleting and reinstalling Firefox as well as downloading and reinstalling a new gecko driver version - all to no avail :(

Comment: Well found the issue but not sure why it's happening. If I kill off all the `options` then the site is scraped fine...